# How can I indent every second visual row, caused by overflow wrapping, within a responsive div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, responsive

Currently working on a responsive hexagon grid in react with styled components. At present it is a single table row (or flexbox - functionality is the same) that repositions all divs when the window changes - great! But every second row needs it have a `margin-left: 56px;`. This needs to happen dynamically/reactively because the number of hexagons rendered will change constantly.

I have tried looking around at overflowing divs into other divs - which would be a great solution but I cannot find out to implement it. I've also tried looking into tracking the position of the Hexagons and when they move down adding a margin and when they move across removing it - but I can't work out how to do it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <HexRow>
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
        <Hex />
      </HexRow>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const HexRow = styled.div`
    clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-left: 55px;
`

const Hex = styled.div`
  &:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
  }

    width: 104px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #6C6;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-right: 10px;

  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
  }
`;

export default App;
```

[What happens now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFGVG.png)

[What needs to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sywjZ.png)

Any helps or pointers is appreciated!

Comment: I think you can do that with just CSS. Check the odd and even pseudo selectors - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: For each visual row, is it always the same number of hexagons? When you say responsive, do you mean responsive page like when you resize the page will change its view to fit the resolution? or responsive as in the number of total hexagons can vary

Comment: @Huamgism each visual row will always have the same number - but that number will change depending on the width of the div. the total number of hexagons will also vary as this component will be used in multiple places

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `:nth-child(even)` CSS selector, as illustrated rather trivially below...

Note that the property you seek is called `margin-left` (not `left-margin`).

```css
div p:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hex</p>
  <p>Hex</p>
  <p>Hex</p>
  <p>Hex</p>
  <p>Hex</p>
  <p>Hex</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not every other item that needs indenting though a it's only the one that's at the beginning of a new line i.e. Each time one of the hexagons is wrapped and pushed onto a new line in the browser then that hexagon needs to be indented (or the line that it is moved on to)

Comment: @JackOddy The same should apply to your _"But every second row..."_ from the original question, I just omitted the _row_ structure for simplicity of the answer. Simply apply the `:nth-child` to the row instead of the hex element.

Comment: But there's nothing in the second row, to make it responsive it's just one row of hexagons that are being wrapped within the div they're in. It's not technically a second row in terms of an HTML element, just looks like it - will remove the row2 div from the snippet to make it clearer